# airflow: how can i put the method for read a json file in a local library

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I must generate some dag. I've saved the json table schema files on [GCP bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets).
The files on the GCP bucket associates to ***composer*** will be remapped on */home/airflow/gcs/dags/*.
If i **define** the method for read the json file, **after** the creation of the dag, all goes fine.
But if I wish generate some "common code" (for put it on a library of mine), I can't access to FileSystem using the code in the library, in the specific I can't use the python json library.

The strange thing is that, I define the method out of the dag creation step, but I invoke it only after the dag creation!

To complete the discussion, i haven't problems if the code in the library uses only in memory objects.

I've this issue when i work with airflow (1.9 on GCP driver by composer)

This is my external library:

```
lib/
    __init__.py
    bb_airflow_utils.py
```

## on external library

```py
def load_json_file(fname):
    #per far sì che il dag la veda
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        d = json.load(f)
    return d
```

## on principal script

```py
from lib.bb_airflow_utils import *
ROOT_PATH = 'home/airflow/gcs/dags'
IDCLI = 'goofy'
...
...
with DAG(dag_id=dag_name, default_args=dag_args) as dag:
    filepath = path.join(ROOT_PATH, '{}-todwh.json'.format(IDCLI))
    get_data = load_json_file(filepath)
    .....
    task_dummy_start = DummyOperator(task_id='task_{}_start'.format(dag_name), dag=dag)
    .....
```

Airflow ignore the operator and by UI said that the dag has not SLA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local.

You can put common code in a separate file and put it in separate folder like the example below.

Place the dependencies within a subdirectory in the `dags/` folder. To import a module from a subdirectory, each subdirectory in the module's path must contain a `__init__.py` package marker file.

In this example, the dependency is coin_module.py:

```
dags/
  use_local_deps.py  # A DAG file.
  dependencies/
    __init__.py
    coin_module.py
```

Import the dependency from the DAG definition file.

For example:

```
from dependencies import coin_module
```

Comment: Hi @kaxil
after your response I've added more details at the question.
But by change, is necessary that the name of the directory is ***dependencies***?

Comment: No, the name of the directory can be anything

Comment: And Change your ROOT_PATH to ROOT_PATH = '/home/airflow/gcs/dags'

Comment: Thanks Kaxil, this was the problem!
Now the code works, i did not find any error but only that the dag was with no SLAS.
Thanks again