# Airfllow cannot find json file

Tags: python, airflow

I've the following structure on my Aitflow process:

```
dags/mainDag.py
dags/BigQuery/deleteData.py
dags/BigQuery/insertData.py
dags/support/gcp.json
dags/support/__init__py
```

My `mainDag.py` is calling `deleteData.py` and the `insertData.py` and this works! But my problem is: In these both files I use the `gcp.json` like this:

```
credentialsPath = "~/airflow/dags/support/gqp.json"
bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(credentialsPath)
```

And in the Airflow Webserver I had this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/airflow/dags/support/gqp.json'

But I can cat the file content on my bash using this path successfully.
I read this two question in the stack, [[airflow: how can i put the method for read a json file in a local library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55453398/airflow-how-can-i-put-the-method-for-read-a-json-file-in-a-local-library][1]) and [[Airflow - Python file NOT in the same DAG folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510365/airflow-python-file-not-in-the-same-dag-folder][2]) but neither works!
Is there anyone who know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try:

```
import os
credentialsPath = "~/airflow/dags/support/gqp.json"
print(os.path.isfile(credentialsPath))
```

You will see that the output is `False`. This is because python doesn't expand the `~` to your user home directory. You can do this using the [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) function:

```
import os
credentialsPath = os.path.expanduser("~/airflow/dags/support/gqp.json")
print(os.path.isfile(credentialsPath))
```

Now, this will output `True` as your file path has been expanded with your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.path.join(
    os.getenv("AIRFLOW_HOME", ""), "dags/support/gqp.json"
)
```

This should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).